# 0-cycles with null augmentation are boundaries in convex spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Well as the title says I would like to know if given a convex space $ X $, a $0$-cycle (equivalently any $0$-chain, right?), such that its augmentation is null is a boundary? All this in singular homology. I think a cone construction would do the trick but I do not know how. May be the argument is simpler using the reduced homology.

Thanks for any help you could provide.

Comment: Yes, this should be true in any path-connected $X$. Choose a point $x_0$ in $X$, then for any instance of $x$ in the $0$-chain, let $\sigma_x$ be a path from $x_0$ to $x$, regarded as a $1$-simplex. Then the boundary of the resulting $1$-chain is your $0$-chain.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At first, I was a little confused as to how the part of the fixed point would vanish through the boundary operator, given that the coeficients of the simplexes could be arbitrary, but the condition on the augmentation solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path-connectedness of $X$ is sufficient here. You can choose any point $x_0$ in $X$, and for each point $x_i$ in your $0$-chain $c=\sum\eta_i x_i$ you can find a path $p_i:[0,1]→X$ from $x_0$ to $x_i$. Regarded as a singular $1$-simplex $p_i:[v_0v_1]\to X$ via the identification $0≘ v_0,\ 1≘v_1$ , it has boundary $p_i(1)-p_i(0)=x_i-x_0$. Then the sum $\sum η_ip_i$ has the boundary $c$ as all instances of $x_0$ cancel out since, by hypothesis, $\sum η_i=0.$